# How to redirect OpenVPN traffic through Tor along with all server traffic

Tags: openvpn, iptables

I have a VDS server and OpenVPN on it.

I want to redirect all server traffic (including OpenVPN) through Tor.

I tried using [this example](https://gitlab.torproject.org/legacy/trac/-/wikis/doc/TransparentProxy#local-redirection-through-tor) and I was able to redirect server traffic, but OpenVPN traffic started blocking.

Answer (score 0):

#### I'm glad everything is working now.

`/etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

`/etc/tor/torrc`

```
TransPort 10.5.0.1:9040 IsolateClientAddr IsolateClientProtocol IsolateDestAddr IsolateDestPort
TransPort 127.0.0.1:9040 IsolateClientAddr IsolateClientProtocol IsolateDestAddr IsolateDestPort
DNSPort 10.5.0.1:5353
DNSPort 127.0.0.1:5353
```

`/etc/openvpn/server.conf`

```
server 10.5.0.0 255.255.255.224
port 1194
```

I adapted the example from [here](https://gitlab.torproject.org/legacy/trac/-/wikis/doc/TransparentProxy#local-redirection-and-anonymizing-middlebox)

```
#!/bin/bash
### Set variables
# The UID that Tor runs as (varies from system to system)
#_tor_uid="109" #As per assumption
_tor_uid=`id -u debian-tor` #Debian/Ubuntu
#_tor_uid=`id -u tor` #ArchLinux/Gentoo

# Tor's TransPort
_trans_port="9040"

# Tor's DNSPort
_dns_port="5353"

# Tor's VirtualAddrNetworkIPv4
_virt_addr="10.192.0.0/10"

# Your outgoing interface
_out_if="eth0"

# Your incoming interface and assigned local IP (Gateway)
_inc_if="tun0"
_inc_ip="10.5.0.1"

# LAN destinations that shouldn't be routed through Tor
_non_tor="127.0.0.0/8 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16"

# Other IANA reserved blocks (These are not processed by tor and dropped by default)
_resv_iana="0.0.0.0/8 100.64.0.0/10 169.254.0.0/16 192.0.0.0/24 192.0.2.0/24 192.88.99.0/24 198.18.0.0/15 198.51.100.0/24 203.0.113.0/24 224.0.0.0/4 240.0.0.0/4 255.255.255.255/32"

### Don't lock yourself out after the flush
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

### Flush iptables
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F

### *nat PREROUTING (For middlebox)
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d $_virt_addr -i $_inc_if -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j REDIRECT --to-ports $_trans_port
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $_inc_if -p udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports $_dns_port

# Allow lan access for hosts in $_non_tor
for _lan in $_non_tor; do
   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $_inc_if -d $_lan -j RETURN
done

for _iana in $_resv_iana; do
   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $_inc_if -d $_iana -j RETURN
done

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $_inc_if -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j REDIRECT --to-ports $_trans_port

### *nat OUTPUT (For local redirection)
# nat .onion addresses
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d $_virt_addr -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j REDIRECT --to-ports $_trans_port

# nat dns requests to Tor
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports $_dns_port

# Don't nat the Tor process, the loopback, or the local network
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner $_tor_uid -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -j RETURN

# Allow lan access for hosts in $_non_tor
for _lan in $_non_tor; do
  iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d $_lan -j RETURN
done

for _iana in $_resv_iana; do
  iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d $_iana -j RETURN
done

# Redirect all other pre-routing and output to Tor's TransPort
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j REDIRECT --to-ports $_trans_port

### *filter INPUT
# Don't forget to grant yourself ssh access from remote machines before the DROP.
iptables -A INPUT -i $_out_if -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i $_out_if -p udp --dport 1194 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow DNS lookups from connected clients and internet access through tor.
iptables -A INPUT -d $_inc_ip -i $_inc_if -p udp -m udp --dport $_dns_port -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -d $_inc_ip -i $_inc_if -p tcp -m tcp --dport $_trans_port --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j ACCEPT

# Allow INPUT from lan hosts in $_non_tor
# Uncomment these 3 lines to enable.
#for _lan in $_non_tor; do
# iptables -A INPUT -s $_lan -j ACCEPT
#done

# Log & Drop everything else. Uncomment to enable logging.
#iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "Dropped INPUT packet: " --log-level 7 --log-uid
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP

### *filter FORWARD
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP

### *filter OUTPUT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow Tor process output
iptables -A OUTPUT -o $_out_if -m owner --uid-owner $_tor_uid -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

# Allow loopback output
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Tor transproxy magic
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport $_trans_port --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j ACCEPT

# Allow OUTPUT to lan hosts in $_non_tor
# Uncomment these 3 lines to enable.
#for _lan in $_non_tor; do
# iptables -A OUTPUT -d $_lan -j ACCEPT
#done

# Log & Drop everything else. Uncomment to enable logging
#iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "Dropped OUTPUT packet: " --log-level 7 --log-uid
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP

### Set default policies to DROP
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

### Set default policies to DROP for IPv6
#ip6tables -P INPUT DROP
#ip6tables -P FORWARD DROP
#ip6tables -P OUTPUT DROP
```